# Error in code: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I am using this simple python script that defines two functions that calculate the area and volume of a cylinder, given its radius and height:

```
import math

def calculate_area(radius):
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    return area

def calculate_volume(radius, height):
    volume = calculate_area(radius) * height
    return volume

r = 5
h = "10"
volume = calculate_volume(r, h)
print("The volume of the cylinder is:", volume)
```

When I execute the script, I see the following error:
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I have tried Importing the float() function instead of the math module, but it only gives more errors. can somebody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Why `h` is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'h' variable in your code is defined as a string rather than a number.
You must first use the float() function to convert the h variable to a number before passing it to the calculate_volume() function:

```
import math

def calculate_area(radius):
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    return area

def calculate_volume(radius, height):
    volume = calculate_area(radius) * height
    return volume

r = 5
h = "10"
volume = calculate_volume(r, float(h))
print("The volume of the cylinder is:", volume)
```

Comment: This code works thank you, now i understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `h` is a `str` (so it's a sequence actually) and your calculated area is a `float`, so python cannot multiply them. Your `h` should be an int/float.

```
import math

def calculate_base_area(radius:float)->float:
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    return area

def calculate_volume(*,radius: float, height:float)->float:
    volume = calculate_base_area(radius) * height
    return volume

r = 5
h = 10
volume = calculate_volume(radious=r,height=h)
print("The volume of the cylinder is:", volume)
```

**Side notes**

- calculate area does not calculate area of the cyllinder, rather its base area, so I'd suggest renaming to avoid confusion later on. The area would be `2*pi*r*h+2*pi*r**2` (side area+2 base areas)
- use type hints, this will make your IDE tell you about this kind of mistakes before running the code
- when the order of the parameters matters it's good to enforce using keyword arguments in your function (this will prevent using height and radious interchangeably which would lead to errors)
- if invalid arguments can be passed to your function use `try...carch` inside to handle that